# After truffle init I don't see MetaCoin.sol and other files expected to be there?

Tags: solidity, truffle, ethereumj

I have Truffle installed on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box.  Here are my Truffle and Solidity version numbers:

```
Truffle v4.0.6 (core: 4.0.6)
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)
```

I am following along the Blockgeeks "How To Learn Solidity" tutorial:

https://blockgeeks.com/guides/solidity/

After running Truffle init, that guide *and other tutorials I have seen on the Web* say I should have the following files in the directories created by the Truffle init command:

- contracts\ConvertLib.sol
- contracts\MetaCoin.sol
- **contracts\Migrations.sol**
- **migrations\1_initial_migration.js**
- migrations\2_initial_migration.js

I only have the files marked in bold.  The other files are missing.  Does anyone know how I get the other files?

Comment: truffle unbox Metacoin is the new command...truffle init is depreccated.

Comment: @cmr Thanks, that did it.  If you're so inclined, please change your comment to an answer and I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: Thank you for your motivation.Its really means a lot for a beginner like me.  Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In truffle v4, `truffle init` is deprecated in favor of `truffle unbox`.

`truffle unbox` just creates the contracts/ and migrations/. directories and a blank truffle.js.

Inorder to unbox Metacoin use the following command.  `truffle unbox MetaCoin`.

You can refer other boilerplates from the following link. http://truffleframework.com/boxes/

Answer (score 3):

From Truffle 4.0.0, "init" only creates a bare environment. Quoting  [document here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v4.0.0):

> Speaking of boxes, truffle init now creates a bare Truffle project. If you'd like a specific example, try a box instead!

As cmr commented, Metacoin can be unboxed, see [main site](http://truffleframework.com/boxes/metacoin).

`truffle unbox metacoin`